# VB Net - String Format not correctly working on escaping double quotes

Tags: vb.net

I've been looking at a few of these questions on StackOverflow but can't seem to work out why I can't get any of the resolutions working.

I have the following code:

```
Imports System
                
Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        dim myFirstName as string = "John"
        dim myLastName as string = "Smith"
        
        dim name as string = String.Format("<Person FirstName=\"{0}\" LastName=\"{1}\">", myFirstName, myLastName)
    End Sub
End Module
```

and I'm passing in two variables that need to be enclosed in double quotes.

I keep getting an error for comma ) or another expression continuation continued.

I've got this on .Net Fiddle to try and replicate this.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/jpDL04

Comment: If you are using VS2015 or later, you could use `Dim name = $"<Person FirstName=""{myFirstName}"" LastName=""{myLastName}"">"`. More info: [Interpolated Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
dim name as string = String.Format("<Person FirstName=""{0}"" LastName=""{1}"">", myFirstName, myLastName)
```

Using 2 double-quotes instead.  The backslash is a C# escape.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Embedded Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/xml/embedded-expressions-in-xml) is an option

```
Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Console.Title = "Code sample"
        Dim myFirstName As String = "John"
        Dim myLastName As String = "Smith"
        Dim name = (<T><%= Chr(60) %>Person FirstName="<%= myFirstName %>" LastName="<%= myLastName %>"<%= Chr(62) %></T>).Value
        Console.WriteLine(name)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```